# No host name resolution on VPN connection

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I have an ASUS wireless router (RT-AC68U) which allows to create a VPN server. I set up the VPN server (PPTP) and I was able to connect to it from the Internet. The problem is that when I connect to it from the outside it cannot resolve host names. `nslookup` works fine from the outside network, but ping and netbios do not work. I tried refreshing dns cache, restarting dns client service, but nothing helped. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Can you ping the devices by IP successfully?

Comment: @ Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: yes